# Google calendar by PHP cURL returned strings in German

Tags: php, curl, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to retrieve the Google calendar XML using cURL to display it in my application.
The calender is public and it can be directly accessed via browser:
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic

When I tried to get it from my program, it is strangely returned in German. Here it is

[image]

Below is my code:

```
$xml = NULL;
$url = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic';

$crl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);

$xml = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
exit;       
if($xml){       
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
}
```

When the URL is run from the browser, it is returned in English. I thought that it is because of the cURL proxy settings on the server, then I tried to add those two lines, but it did not make sense.

```
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, FALSE);
```

Any idea? Please help.

Comment: Append url `..../basic?hl=en`?

Comment: Your server location could be the cause. But as Bora said, its a simple solution to request in a specific language.

Comment: @Bora, yes, `?hl=en` did work. Thanks! Why did you not add an answer? But I wonder why it returns in English without `hl=en` when I run from the browser. Is it because of my location?

Comment: @Sithu, I'd imagine your server is located in Germany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append to url `?hl=en`

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic?hl=en';
```

Cause of this as @CharliePrynn said: Your server location could be the cause